# My completely managed assembly crashes with an AccessViolationException on .Net 4.5?

Tags: .net, debugging, jit, .net-4.5, il

I've been debugging a very thorny issue.

Basically, I have an obfuscated assembly that crashes in various ways . The unobfuscated assembly has no problems, though there is no guarantee the obfuscator isn't to blame here. (that's what I might be aiming to fix)

Anyway, The obfuscated assembly also runs fine on .Net 4.0. It runs fine if I disable JIT optimizations in .Net 4.5.

What I've tried:

I tried debugging it against the IL. The access violation appears to come from an IL operation that simply loads something onto the stack. Again, completely managed code.

Just in case it's related to the [String.Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873798/whats-the-cause-of-this-fatalexecutionengineerror-in-net-4-5-beta), I went through the IL and replaced all of the string::empty calls with `ldstr ""`.. Now, instead of an AccessViolation, I get a FatalEngineException

Running it through a deobfuscator with all of it's options turned off makes it work though. Basically, all that the deobfuscator does with nothing turned on is just barely rearrange the IL and insert some NOPs.

Also, the executable does pass PEVerify, so that's not a concern.

The bad executable: [Test.exe](http://lastyearswishes.com/static/Test.exe)

The good executable: [Test-cleaned.exe](http://lastyearswishes.com/static/Test-cleaned.exe)

The offending stacktrace:

```
Test.exe!PreEmptive.SoS.Client.Cache.CacheService.ServiceCache() Line 22032 + 0x137 bytes   Unknown
Test.exe!Test.TestConsole.Main(string[] args) Line 14 + 0x6 bytes   Unknown
```

You can use ildasm to compare the two executables. Because it's reordered though, I found it a bit too difficult for my taste. I made a [small tool](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/ildump/overview) to just dump the method's IL and have the methods in a sorted order for ease of comparison.

The bad IL dump: [testcount.il](http://lastyearswishes.com/static/testcount.il)

The good IL dump: [testcountcleaned.il](http://lastyearswishes.com/static/testcountcleaned.il)

Anyway, if anyone has any ideas on how to analyze this and figure out exactly what pieces of IL are causing this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that we did actually have a tiny bit of P/Invoking. .Net 4.5 uses memory more aggressively. For some reason, a tool we were using stripped out the Marshalling attribute on one of our structs. After fixing that bug, everything magically works. So, it's not a .Net 4.5 bug at all. It just uses memory more aggressively now.