# Changed behavior of string.Empty (or System.String::Empty) in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, readonly, string

**Short version:**

The C# code

```
typeof(string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, "Hello world!");
Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
```

when compiled and run, gives output `"Hello world!"` under .NET version 4.0 and earlier, but gives `""` under .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.1.

How can a write to a field be ignored like that, or, who resets this field?

**Longer version:**

I have never really understood why the `string.Empty` field (also known as `[mscorlib]System.String::Empty`) is not `const` (aka. `literal`), see "[Why isn't String.Empty a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/)". This means that, for example, in C# we can't use `string.Empty` in the following situations:

- In a `switch` statement in the form `case string.Empty:`
- As the default value of an optional parameter, like `void M(string x = string.Empty) { }`
- When applying an attribute, like `[SomeAttribute(string.Empty)]`
- Other situations where a compile-time constant is required

which has implications to the well-known "religious war" over whether to use `string.Empty` or `""`, see "[In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or "" to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/)".

A couple of years ago I amused myself by setting `Empty` to some other string instance through reflection, and see how many parts of the BCL started behaving strangely because of it. It was quite many. And the change of the `Empty` reference seemed to persist for the complete life of the application. Now, the other day I tried to repeat that little stunt, but then using a .NET 4.5 machine, and I couldn't do it anymore.

(NB! If you have .NET 4.5 on your machine, probably your `PowerShell` still uses an older version of .NET (*EDIT: only true for Windows 7 or older where PowerShell has not been updated beyond PowerShell 2.0*), so try copy-pasting `[String].GetField("Empty").SetValue($null, "Hello world!")` into PowerShell to see some effects of changing this reference.)

When I tried to search for a reason for this, I stumbled upon the interesting thread "[What's the cause of this FatalExecutionEngineError in .NET 4.5 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873798/)". In the accepted answer to that question, is it noted that through version 4.0, `System.String` had a static constructor `.cctor` in which the field `Empty` was set (in the C# source, that would probably just be a field initializer, of course), while in 4.5 no static constructor exists. In both versions, the field itself looks the same:

```
.field public static initonly string Empty
```

(as seen with IL DASM).

No other fields than `String::Empty` seems to be affected. As an example, I experimented with `System.Diagnostics.Debugger::DefaultCategory`. This case seems analogous: A sealed class containing a `static readonly` (`static initonly`) field of type `string`. But in this case it works fine to change the value (reference) through reflection.

**Back to the question:**

How is it possible, technically, that `Empty` doesn't seem to change (in 4.5) when I set the field? I have verified that the C# compiler does not "cheat" with the read, it outputs IL like:

```
ldsfld     string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
```

so the actual field ought to be read.

---

**Edit after bounty was put on my question:** Note that the write operation (which needs reflection for sure, since the field is `readonly` (a.k.a. `initonly` in the IL)) actually works as expected. It is the ***read*** operation which is anomalous. If you read with reflection, as in `typeof(string).GetField("Empty").GetValue(null)`, everything is normal (i.e. the change of value is seen). See comments below.

So the better question is: Why does this new version of the framework cheat when it reads this particular field?

Comment: It could also be interesting to hear if this is the same with Mono.

Comment: I think this is more suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: While the compiler isn't cheating, there's a decent chance the CLR *is*.

Comment: What happens when you turn right around and print out the value of `string.Empty` using reflection as well?

Comment: @KirkWoll What a great comment! I don't know why I didn't think of doing that. When I _read_ with reflection also, the new value is respected. That means `Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).GetField("Empty").GetValue(null));` does print `"Hello world!"` in 4.5.

Comment: @Renan, not really a better fit for programmers.  The OP asked a specific answerable question that in principle has one correct answer.  SO is ideally suited for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evil code confusion, how does it even compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293924/evil-code-confusion-how-does-it-even-compile)

Comment: @BenVoigt: That other question has barely any connection to this one; the only loose connection being "accessing `string.Empty` with reflection". The other question is about why a `readonly` field in a system assembly can be written to; this one is about why and how a particular field rejects certain reflection-based write-operations in certain versions of .NET.

Comment: @BenVoigt As O. R. Mapper said, it is not a duplicate of the other question. My question is: Why has the behavior of programs like the one we see in the other question _changed between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5_?

Comment: @Jeppe: Both questions are a subset of "What are the implications of breaking .NET global invariants by using reflection to modify `initonly` fields?"  Marking a duplicate does not mean that the questions are worded the same, it means that if you read the other question **and answers**, you would have found the answer to this.

Comment: @BenVoigt Alright, but only because you just expanded your own answer in the other thread, after claiming that this thread is a duplicate of that one. I am fine with merging the questions like that, but since smartcaveman has spent 50 points on a bounty on this thread, this is maybe not the right time to close it.

Comment: Everything I added to that answer was already in comments on other answers. So it's easier to find now and explained more clearly, but the information was already there for anyone who looked.

Answer (score 22):

The difference lies in the JIT for the new release of .NET, which apparently optimizes references to `String.Empty` by inlining a reference to a particular `String` instance rather than load the value stored in the `Empty` field. This is justified under the definition of the **init-only constraint** in ECMA-335 Partition I §8.6.1.2, which can be interpreted to mean the value of the `String.Empty` field will not change after the `String` class is initialized.

Comment: Also, in .NET 4 the `System.String` class had a static constructor (method `.cctor()`) which assigned to the field. In .NET 4.5 and later, that is no longer the case. I wonder why a read through reflection (which doesn't seem to "cheat") doesn't see the field as `null` then.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer, juste some hint, maybe.

The only difference I see between `String::Empty` and `System.Diagnostics.Debugger::DefaultCategory` is the first one is tagged with `__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute`.

I dont' known the meaning of this undocumented attribute. A question about this attribute has been asked on SO: [What is the __DynamicallyInvokable attribute for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550749/what-is-the-dynamicallyinvokable-attribute-for)

I can only suppose that this attribute is catch by the runtime to do some caching ?

Answer (score 2):

Because it can.

The value of these system-defined `initonly` fields are global invariants for the .NET runtime.  If these invariants are broken, there are no longer *any guarantees whatsoever* regarding the behavior.

In C++, we would probably have a rule designating this as causing *undefined behavior*.  In .NET, it is also undefined behavior, simply by the absence of any rule saying what happens when `System.String.Empty.Length > 0`.  The whole specification of all layers of .NET and C# describe the behavior when `System.String.Empty.Length == 0` and a whole bunch of invariants also hold.

For more information about optimizations which vary between runtimes and the implications, see the answers to

- [What are the implications of asking Reflection APIs to overwrite System.String.Empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293924/103167)