# Empty string as a special case?

Tags: c#, .net

I read Jon Skeet's quiz and I wondered why the second sample of mine won't work while the first one does.

Why does this yield `true` :

```
object x = new string("".ToArray());
object y = new string("".ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(x == y); //true
```

But this one does not:

```
var k="k";
//string.intern(k); // doesn't help
object x = new string(k.ToArray());
object y = new string(k.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(x == y); //false
```

*I'm using  fw 4.5 with vs2010.*

Luckily I also have vs2005 installed , same results :

[image]

Comment: What version of .NET are you using that allows you to take a single string element to an array? Or maybe I should ask what includes you are using?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman string is an Ienumerable of chars....

Comment: So you have include LINQ as well?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman that doesn't matter.If you wish you can use `String.ToCharArray` that's the same

Comment: If you compare like this `x.Equals(y)` then it will return true

Comment: `intern` is not required as literals are interned by default. Also can you check with the machine only has .net3.5 or .Net4.0 ? because [behavior of String.Empty is changed from .Net 4.5 onwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618302/changed-behavior-of-string-empty-or-system-stringempty-in-net-4-5) May be that is the reason!

Comment: @dholakiyaankit but that's value comparison dude we're talking about reference equality here

Comment: If you change the first example to use `object x = new String("k".ToArray());`, it also fails the comparison.

Comment: Ok i don't know why this is happening?

Comment: This is really a good question

Comment: @dholakiyaankit because strings are compared by value instead of reference see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: Then shouldn't the "k" string be equal to the other "k" string if they are compared by value?

Comment: Also, using `object c = new String(String.Empty.ToArray());` compares to True.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman but they are defined as object thus compared by reference. if you define them as string, then it will return true.

Comment: @RoyiNamir As I said earlier someone has to test this with machine which doesn't even have .Net 4.5 installed, You have .Net 4.5 installed isn't it? So that won't help as new binaries of .Net4.5 will be used there even though you target to .net 2.0.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel 4.5 extends/overwrites fw 4. not 2. if you have installed 2, it will use it. (imho). ( and I do have it installed)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, may be am wrong at this

Comment: Using the new Reference Source, we can easily see that in the source code: [string.cs, line 1687](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#1687), and [line 1722](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#1722). Of course, that's just one implementation, you should count on the spec, not the source code.

Comment: @Kobi please convert your comment to answer..

Comment: @Royi - I looked for it after reading the top answer, so it's already there: "Some versions of the .NET runtime automatically intern the empty string at runtime, some do not!". But thanks!

Comment: @Kobi I'm having a problem selecting it since 98% of the answer is things I already know and mentioned. ( as I said : it doesn't help). only his last line really answer the question. but yours also provide the source code .

Comment: Can someone add a link to the quiz please?

Comment: I'm not sure why you accepted the answer below, it didn't even address the contents of the question. In your first example, you used string constructors to instantiate the empty strings. That should have given completely new references and not the same.

Comment: @JeffMercado you didn't read the answers. An empty string in runtime is also interened

Comment: I did, but the literal `""` and `String.Empty` are different beasts than `new String(new char[0])`. As far as I see it, none of the answers really address that. And the quote from Eric Lippert's blog was pulled out of context. It was talking about empty string literals and `String.Empty`. The case of two independently newed strings, that happen to be empty is still unclear. All answers just conveniently danced around that explanation.

Comment: @jeff Some versions of the .NET runtime automatically intern the empty string at runtime, some do not. So the value of new string("".toarray()) will also be interened as it is an empty steing as result

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably dwelling on that bit too much. Reading that in the context of the blog reads different to me for whatever reason. The idea of `new T() != new T()` for all `T` not always being true is just blowing my mind right now.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a blog post by Eric Lippert which answers your question: [String interning and String.Empty](https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/).

He's describing similar situation:

```
object obj = "Int32";
string str1 = "Int32";
string str2 = typeof(int).Name;
Console.WriteLine(obj == str1); // true
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // true
Console.WriteLine(obj == str2); // false !?
```

So the idea is, that interning does not mean you'll have only one instance of particular `string`, even when it's interned. **Only compile time literals are interned by default**. It means that following code prints true:

```
var k1 = "k";
object k2 = "k";
Console.WriteLine(k1 == k2);
```

But, if you try to create string with `"k"` content programmatically at runtime, e.g. using `string(char[])` constructor, calling `ToString()` on an object, using `StringBuilder`, etc, you won't get interned string by default. This one prints false;

```
var k1 = "k";
object k2 = new string("k".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(k1 == k2);
```

Why? Because interning strings at runtime is expensive.

> There Ain't No Such Thing As A Free Lunch.
>
> (...)
>
> **In short, it is in the general case not worth it to intern all strings.**

And about different behavior with empty string:

> Some versions of the .NET runtime automatically intern the empty string at runtime, some do not!

Comment: Then why does Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); print true

Comment: @Him Because they are declared as `string` and `String` class overrides `==` operator to perform string comparison, not reference equality check.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question though? In the examples given, the strings are all created through the constructors. No string literals are used (and thus no interning).

Comment: Please explain how it is possible for `ReferenceEquals(new string(new char[]{}), new string(new char[]{})) == true`. I’m guessing this has to do with the constructor being marked `extern` in the reference source—i.e., it’s not something that could be implemented with pure C#, right?

Comment: @JeffMercado, maybe arrays of zero size and the same type get interned as well as strings?

Answer (score 11):

Note that interning the *new* strings in the second block of code *does* make them equal.

```
var k="k";
object x = string.Intern(new string(k.ToArray()));
object y = string.Intern(new string(k.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(x == y); //true
```

It seems like it's interning the empty strings automatically, but non-empty strings aren't interned unless they're done explicitly (or they're literal strings which are always interned).

I'm guessing that yes, empty strings are being treated as a special case and being interned automatically, probably because the check is so trivial that it doesn't add any real performance penalty (we can safely say that ANY string of length 0 is the empty string and is identical to any other empty string -- all other strings require us to look at the characters and not just the length).

Comment: All constant string literals are interned by default.

Comment: This returns true because your code is same as `object x = "k"; object y = "k"` which interns by default. Question is Why new new `string(k.ToArray())` gives new instance where as `new string("".ToArray())` gives interned instance ?

Answer (score 6):

The first case compares 2 references to the same object (`String.Empty`). Calling `operator==` for 2 `object` variables causes their comparance by reference and gives `true`.

The second case produces 2 different instances of string class. Their reference comparison gives `false`

If you give `string` type to `x` and `y` in the second case the `string.operator==` override will be called and the comparison gives `true`

Note that we don't deal with the string interning directly in both cases. The string objects which we compare are created using `string(char[])` constructor. Apparently that constructor is designed to return the value of the `string.Empty` field when called with an empty array as an argument.

The answer posted by MarcinJuraszek referes to the [Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx) which discusses string interning. That blog post discusses other corner case of string class usage. Consider this example from the forementioned Lippert's blog:

```
object obj = "";
string str1 = "";
string str2 = String.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(obj == str1); // true
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // true
Console.WriteLine(obj == str2); // sometimes true, sometimes false?!
```

What we see here is that the assignment from the empty string literal (`""`) is not guaranteed to produce the reference to the static readonly `System.String.Empty` field.

Let's look at the IL for the `object x = new string("".ToArray());` expression:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr      ""
IL_0006:  call       !!0[] [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray<char>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
IL_000b:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.String::.ctor(char[])
IL_0010:  stloc.0
```

The interning may (or may not) happen at the IL_0001 line. Whether the literal is interned or not, the `ToArray()` method produces a new empty array and the `String::.ctor(char[])` gives us `String.Empty`.

What we see here is not the special case of `string.Empty` but rather is one of the side effects of the `string` class being reference type and immutable at the same time. There are other immutable framework types which have predefined values with similar semantics (like `DateTime.MinValue`). But as far as I know such framework types are defined as `struct` unlike the `string` which is a reference type. The value types are totally different story... It does not make sense to return some fixed predefined type instance from a mutable class constructor (the calling code will be able to change that instance and cause the unpredictable behavior of the type). So the *reference* types whose constructors do not always return new instances may exist provided that those types are immutable. I am not aware of other such types in the framework though, except the `string`.

Comment: _The second case produces 2 different instances of string class_ **OK**. if so - why does the first one does not _produces 2 different instances of string class_ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Probably string(char[]) ctor is designed that way. .net has the special empty string object. So it returns `string.Empty` when the constructor receives the empty array.

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev: Are there any other types whose constructors do not always return new instances?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I've tried to clarify my point of view here. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

My hypothesis is why the first one yields true while the 2nd yields false:

The first result my be an optimization, take the following code code

```
Enumerable.Empty<char>() == Enumerable.Empty<char>() // true
```

So, suppose the `ToArray` method returns `Enumerable.Empty<char>()` when the string is empty, this would explain why the first result yields true and the 2nd doesn't, as it's doing a reference check.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx

`In the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1, the Intern method reverts to its behavior in the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1 with regard to interning the empty string...`

`...In the .NET Framework 1.0, .NET Framework 1.1, and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, ~empty strings~ are equal`

This means, empty strings are both interned by default, even when constructing from an empty array, and are therefore equal.

Furthermore:

`The .NET Framework version 2.0 introduces the CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning enumeration member`

This most likely provides you a way to create a consistent way to compare, although as @BenM suggests, you would rather explicitly use the Intern function.

Given the boxing that occurs, you could also use `string.Equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2):

I think This can be the reason I refer **Jon Skeet** Answer
about String Comparison

[Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

```
        object x1 = new StringBuilder("").ToString().ToArray();
        object y1 = new StringBuilder("").ToString().ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(x1 == y1); //true

        Console.WriteLine("Address x1:" + Get(x1));
        Console.WriteLine("Address y1:" + Get(y1));

        var k = "k";
        //string.intern(k); // doesn't help
        object x = new string(k.ToArray());
        object y = new string(k.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(x == y); //false

        Console.WriteLine("Address x:" + Get(x));
        Console.WriteLine("Address y:" + Get(y));

        Console.Read();
```

Output

```
False
Address x1:0x2613E5
Address y1:0x2613E5
False
Address x:0x2613E5
Address y:0x2613E5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special case where empty strings always return the same object and this is why when you compare if the object is the same in this case its true.

**[Edit]: previous code was using string comparator instead of object**

```
object a = "s";
object b = "d";

a = ((string)a).Replace("s", "");
b = ((string)b).Replace("d", "");

Console.WriteLine(a == b);

object c = "sa";
object d = "da";

c = ((string)c).Replace("s", "");
d = ((string)d).Replace("d", "");

Console.WriteLine(c == d);

c = ((string)c).Replace("a", "");
d = ((string)d).Replace("a", "");

Console.WriteLine(c == d);
```

result

```
True
False
True
```