# Why can't I use string.Empty as an optional parameter contrary to empty quotation marks?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I'm refining my code and noticed that at some places I had optional parameters with the default value of an empty string. I changed that to a default value from the class for empty string and guess what! Apparently there's a difference between empty quotation marks and `string.Empty`. What the duck?! (typo intended)

```
private void Khaboom(String parameter = "") { ... }

private void Bazinga(String parameter = String.Empty) { ... }
```

Can someone explain to me why the duck does `Khaboom` work while `Bazinga` doesn't?!

The error message whines this:

> Default parameter value for 'parameter' must be a compile-time constant.

Well... It **is**!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Duplicated what?

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate but then reopened it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Empty` is defined as follows:

```
public static readonly string Empty
```

It's not a constant. It's a readonly field.

Comment: And for those wondering why it is not a constant, there might actually be a [very good reason for that](http://www.stum.de/2009/01/14/const-strings-a-very-convenient-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot/).

Comment: @Scott... I did wonder... thx.

Comment: @Scott Your link gives absolutely no good reason why `string.Empty` was not chosen to be a `const` field. The reason is much more obscure. There are threads on this topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507923/why-isnt-string-empty-a-constant

Comment: Note that the old (problematic?) decision to not make `string.Empty` a literal, was possibly compensated for with the .NET 4.5 version. Actually, since 4.5, when you read from `string.Empty`, with IL code created by the C# compiler for instance, the runtime ["cheats"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618302/) and substitutes an empty string instead of reading the actual string reference held by the static field. This optimization appears to make `string.Empty` more const-like when the code runs. But at compile-time it is still not a true constant, of course, so the above answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

Since `string.Empty` is neither of these things, it is not allowed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: s/neither of these things/none of these things

Answer (score 2):

Default parameter values are required to be constants, but String.Empty is a read only field.