# Optional parameters “must be a compile-time constant” with a const still bugging

Tags: c#, constants, optional-parameters

I've read both

[Optional parameters "must be a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7672005/684646)

And

[Default parameter for value must be a compile time constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18740421/684646)

But this keeps not compiling on the declaration, marking `Empty` as a non constant.

```
public class MyClass
{
private const string Empty = string.Empty;

private string WriteFailedList(string prefix = Empty, DeployResponse Ret)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var errorItems = Ret.Items.TakeWhile(item => item.Status == DeployItem.ItemStatus.Error);
        foreach (var item in errorItems)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} {1}",prefix,item.Filename));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

@Edit: Code good practice suggestions taken from Jon Skeet.

Comment: That code doesn't give me that error - it gives me "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters".

Comment: Awkward, I'll do that to see if it vanishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use string.Empty as an optional parameter contrary to empty quotation marks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984972/why-cant-i-use-string-empty-as-an-optional-parameter-contrary-to-empty-quotatio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've given has two problems:

- Optional parameters must come last (apart from `params` parameters)
- `const` fields must be assigned compile-time constants, and `string.Empty` *isn't* a const field
- Because `Empty` isn't a valid `const`, your default value isn't `const`. This is just a corollary of the second issue

Both of these are easily fixed:

```
private const string Empty = ""; // Literal rather than String.Empty
...

// Parameter name changed to be more readable and conventional
private string WriteFailedList(DeployResponse response, string prefix = Empty)
{
    ...
}
```

Or get rid of your own `Empty` constant:

```
private string WriteFailedList(DeployResponse response, string prefix = "")
{
    ...
}
```

(I'd also advise you to use `camelCase` for your parameters and local variables - so `errorItems` rather than `ErrorItems`. Or just `errors`, in fact. I'd also use a `foreach` loop instead of calling `ToList()` and then using `ForEach`.)

Comment: I was just thinking on this, when I changed the order as you suggested, string.Empty yelled at me that it wasn't a constant.
Seems that the error came from .net "noncompiled" code suggestions.